# Can a SQL Server DBA be restricted from viewing the information in the database?

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-administration

Because of some data privacy regulations, my company may need to have a DBA work with things like mirroring, index rebuilds, log shipping, clustering general system maintenance things like that while not having access to view the information in the database tables.

This sounds impossible to me, but is it at all possible to give someone access to do anything with a database except view the data included?

Answer (score 0):

DBAs (i.e.sysadmin or sa rights) have no restrictions on their activities.

So only if the data is stored encrypted from the client code. But what about client code developers, Windows admins, network admins, web server admins etc? And those pesky users with their USB pens.

Comment: thanks gbn, about what i expected. the use case is that we are expanding a US based regulatory compliance app to Europe. because of data privacy regulations, customer data cannot be accessed from the US. we would like to have the ability to have our US based team back up the UK based team as needed. 

client code developers wouldnt concern me because they dont develop against customer data, admins et al dont concern me because mostly they will be only running the servers and won't have rights to the database (and will be uk based). and the users own the data, so i dont care about them either.